# How to set $x>0$ for equation in CAS in GeoGebra?

Tags: math-software

I tried writing it like in the screenshot below, but that didn't work. Is there a command for this?

[image]

Comment: One way is to not require $x>0$ from GeoGebra, and instead impose that yourself after getting $\pm 1$ as the two solutions.

Comment: @Arthur I tried writing $x>0$ in a new row now, but got question mark? I know it's possible to get it all in one row. It's not important for me heh, but maybe it looks better/cleaner for the examiner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out now, the command is `Solve( <Equation in x> )`

[image]